# Windows 10 sound driver disable after sleep/restart

Tags: windows, audio, drivers

I'm having an infuriating problem with my XPS 13. After a Windows 10 update it seems my sound driver stopped working. As in, it's still recognised in Device Manager, but the task bar says that 'no audio output devices' are installed. The only way to get the audio working is to boot into Ubuntu, select the audio driver and enable it (it's disabled by default when starting Ubuntu). Then, once booted into Windows, the audio functions, but only for that session; once the computer has been rebooted or put to sleep the audio disables again and must be reenabled in Ubuntu.

I've tried reinstalling drivers multiple times. I really have no idea what to do now. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is this on board audio? Have you tried older drivers? Are you obtaining the drivers from the manufacturers website?

Comment: @Jamie Did you solve that problem by now? The exact same problem occured on my laptop re recently. Also XPS 13 and Windows 10.